# Django - Hide legend in Highcharts from Python script

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, highcharts

I would like your help for a little project I'm doing with Django and Highcharts.js.

**My target:** hide legend in Highcharts's chart from my script views.py

From my views.py file I have managed to be able to correctly plot different types of charts.
But I can't hide the legend from views.py.

To give an example I have borrowed the code from this [django-highcharts-example](https://github.com/sibtc/django-highcharts-example) tutorial in Github.

Here is the example code to replicate the behaviour of the script:

**views.py**

```
def ticket_class_view_3(request):
    dataset = Passenger.objects \
        .values('ticket_class') \
        .annotate(survived_count=Count('ticket_class', filter=Q(survived=True)),
                  not_survived_count=Count('ticket_class', filter=Q(survived=False))) \
        .order_by('ticket_class')

    categories = list()
    survived_series_data = list()
    not_survived_series_data = list()

    for entry in dataset:
        categories.append('%s Class' % entry['ticket_class'])
        survived_series_data.append(entry['survived_count'])
        not_survived_series_data.append(entry['not_survived_count'])

    survived_series = {
        'name': 'Survived',
        'data': survived_series_data,
        'color': 'green'
    }

    not_survived_series = {
        'name': 'Survived',
        'data': not_survived_series_data,
        'color': 'red',
        'showInLegend': "false"    }

    chart = {
        'chart': {'type': 'column'},
        'title': {'text': 'Titanic Survivors by Ticket Class'},
        'xAxis': {'categories': categories},
        'series': [survived_series, not_survived_series],
        'plotOptions': {'column': {'showInLegend': 'false'}}
    }

    dump = json.dumps(chart)

    return render(request, 'ticket_class_3.html', {'chart': dump})
```

The html where I import Highcharts.js and create the charts.

**ticket_class_3.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Django Highcharts Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Return to homepage</a>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
  <script>
    Highcharts.chart('container', {{ chart|safe }});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to hide the legend as it is in the example code above in views.py

```
'plotOptions': {'column': {'showInLegend': 'false'}}
```

I have also tried it when creating the series with the same result: the legend still appears.

```
        not_survived_series = {
        'name': 'Survived',
        'data': not_survived_series_data,
        'color': 'red',
        'showInLegend': "false"}
```

However, if I add this showInLegend option in the html code, it works correctly. But **I would like to be able to do it from Python**. Is it possible, can you help me?

If you need an example easier to execute, let me know and I'll try to prepare it.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the error in my code. It seems that when you configure the charts from Python and you have to declare a boolean value you have to declare it as True/False not as "true" or "false".

So to hide the legend in my code I would have to replace *'plotOptions': {'column': {'showInLegend': "false"}}* by '*plotOptions': {'column': {'showInLegend': False}}*.

```
def ticket_class_view_3(request):
    dataset = Passenger.objects \
        .values('ticket_class') \
        .annotate(survived_count=Count('ticket_class', filter=Q(survived=True)),
                  not_survived_count=Count('ticket_class', filter=Q(survived=False))) \
        .order_by('ticket_class')

    categories = list()
    survived_series_data = list()
    not_survived_series_data = list()

    for entry in dataset:
        categories.append('%s Class' % entry['ticket_class'])
        survived_series_data.append(entry['survived_count'])
        not_survived_series_data.append(entry['not_survived_count'])

    survived_series = {
        'name': 'Survived',
        'data': survived_series_data,
        'color': 'green'
    }

    not_survived_series = {
        'name': 'Survived',
        'data': not_survived_series_data,
        'color': 'red' }


    chart = {
        'chart': {'type': 'column'},
        'title': {'text': 'Titanic Survivors by Ticket Class'},
        'xAxis': {'categories': categories},
        'series': [survived_series, not_survived_series],
        'plotOptions': {'column': {'showInLegend': False}}
    }

    dump = json.dumps(chart)

    return render(request, 'ticket_class_3.html', {'chart': dump})
```

I propose to close this thread.